# Deploy a Next.js App to Cloudflare Pages with LaunchDarkly

Tags: next.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, launchdarkly

I have a Next.js 13 app that was deployed to the Edge on Cloudflare Pages with `experimental: { runtime: 'experimental-edge' }`, but requirements were updated and I need to include our feature flag dependency [LaunchDarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/) - and retrieve the feature flags via `getServerSideProps`.

Inside `getServerSideProps` I tried `launchdarkly-node-server-sdk`, `launchdarkly-node-client-sdk`, and `launchdarkly-js-client-sdk`, but they either require a Node specific library (`fs` and others) or `window`.

`launchdarkly-cloudflare-edge-sdk` with `@cloudflare/kv-asset-handler` looks promising, so I followed [the template](https://docs.launchdarkly.com/sdk/server-side/node-js/cloudflare-edge-sdk), but I'm not sure how to extend a Next.js app to have this functionality. For example, do I put the worker into a `middleware.ts` function or somehow extend the `vercel build` step to include this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out but I am guessing you may need to use the Cloudflare SDK throughout since Cloudflare would deploy the functions as Cloudflare Workers, which is a non-Node runtime.

In a typical Next.js deployment, you'd use the Node server SDK for any server side code (like `getServerSideProps`) but my assumption is that this may cause errors due to the fact that it relies upon some Node-specific APIs that I am not sure the Workers runtime supports. We (LaunchDarkly) are working on updates to our JavaScript SDKs to better support non-Node runtimes but I don't have an ETA on their release.